# How to get <access token> in every request using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, api

I'm using Caspio Bridge Database (REST API). I would like to know how can I generate a access token in my every request using AJAX. To get the access token I need: `Client_ID`, `Client_Secret`, `URL_Token`. I have all of this datas.

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  url: 'https://xxxxx.caspio.com/rest/v2/tables/Test_Database_1Million/records',
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  'data': JSON.stringify({
    "UniqueID": "55",
    "Drivers_Full_Name": "My_name"
  }),

  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "BEARER " + access_token); // how to generate automaticaly??
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data.Result);
  },
  error: function(data) {
    console.log(data.responseJSON);
  }
});
```

Comment: [jQuery.ajaxSend](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) use this to intercept ajax requests before they get sent

Comment: Their API documentation should tell you how to generate your access token. I would imagine it involves some form of encryption of those values using a private key

Comment: @phuzi I believe the OP is asking how to generate the access token, not how to add it to the request

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I read it as OP wanted to add access token to every AJAX request

Comment: The comment in the code states `how to generate automaticaly?`

Comment: How to generate and add on the access token variable

Comment: Is that the header or the access token or both?

Comment: https://howto.caspio.com/web-services-api/rest-api/authenticating-rest/ -> _"...for Basic Authentication Realm. It is constructed by creating the string “Client_ID:Client_Secret”, and encoding it using the RFC2045-MIME variant of Base64."_